# FP101x Lab 2 sumDigits

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm stuck on Lab 2 of the Functional Programming course on edX taught by Erik Meijer. I will copy paste the assignment here:

> In this lab, you will implement a validation algorithm for credit cards. The algorithm follows these steps:
>
> ```
>    Double the value of every second digit beginning with the rightmost.
>    Add the digits of the doubled values and the undoubled digits from the original number.
>    Calculate the modulus of the sum divided by 10.
> ```
>
> If the result equals 0, then the number is valid. Here is an example of the results of each step on the number 4012888888881881.
>
> ```
>    In order to start with the rightmost digit, we produce a reversed list of digits. Then, we double every second digit.
> ```
>
> Result: [1,16,8,2,8,16,8,16,8,16,8,16,2,2,0,8].
>
> We sum all of the digits of the resulting list above. Note that we must again split the elements of the list into their digits (e.g. 16 becomes [1, 6]).
>
> Result: 90.
>
> Finally, we calculate the modulus of 90 over 10.
>
> Result: 0.

Since the final value is 0, we know that the above number is a valid credit card number. If we make a mistake in typing the credit card number and instead provide 4012888888881891, then the result of the last step is 2, proving that the number is invalid.

My code:

```
toDigits   :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits n = if 0 <= n && n <= 10 then [n] else toDigits ((n - n `mod` 10) `quot` 10) ++ [n `mod` 10]

toDigitsRev :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigitsRev n = reverse (toDigits n)


doubleSecond :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleSecond xs | length xs <= 1                   = xs
                | 1 < length xs  && length xs < 4  = [fst (splitAt 2 xs) !! 0 ,(*2) (fst (splitAt 2 xs) !! 1 )] ++ snd (splitAt 2 xs)
                | otherwise                        = doubleSecond (fst (splitAt 2 xs)) ++ doubleSecond (snd (splitAt 2 xs))


sumDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumDigits xs | xs == []  = 0
             | otherwise = sum (toDigits (head xs)) + sumDigits (tail xs)

isValid :: Integer -> Bool
isValid n | sumDigits (doubleSecond (toDigitsRev n)) `mod` 10 == 0 = True
          | otherwise                                              = False
```

Next, they give you this code:

```
numValid :: [Integer] -> Integer
numValid xs = sum . map (\_ -> 1) $ filter isValid xs


creditcards :: [Integer]
creditcards = [ 4716347184862961,
                4532899082537349,
                4485429517622493,
                4320635998241421,
                4929778869082405,
                5256283618614517,
                5507514403575522,
                5191806267524120,
                5396452857080331,
                5567798501168013,
                6011798764103720,
                6011970953092861,
                6011486447384806,
                6011337752144550,
                6011442159205994,
                4916188093226163,
                4916699537435624,
                4024607115319476,
                4556945538735693,
                4532818294886666,
                5349308918130507,
                5156469512589415,
                5210896944802939,
                5442782486960998,
                5385907818416901,
                6011920409800508,
                6011978316213975,
                6011221666280064,
                6011285399268094,
                6011111757787451,
                4024007106747875,
                4916148692391990,
                4916918116659358,
                4024007109091313,
                4716815014741522,
                5370975221279675,
                5586822747605880,
                5446122675080587,
                5361718970369004,
                5543878863367027,
                6011996932510178,
                6011475323876084,
                6011358905586117,
                6011672107152563,
                6011660634944997,
                4532917110736356,
                4485548499291791,
                4532098581822262,
                4018626753711468,
                4454290525773941,
                5593710059099297,
                5275213041261476,
                5244162726358685,
                5583726743957726,
                5108718020905086,
                6011887079002610,
                6011119104045333,
                6011296087222376,
                6011183539053619,
                6011067418196187,
                4532462702719400,
                4420029044272063,
                4716494048062261,
                4916853817750471,
                4327554795485824,
                5138477489321723,
                5452898762612993,
                5246310677063212,
                5211257116158320,
                5230793016257272,
                6011265295282522,
                6011034443437754,
                6011582769987164,
                6011821695998586,
                6011420220198992,
                4716625186530516,
                4485290399115271,
                4556449305907296,
                4532036228186543,
                4916950537496300,
                5188481717181072,
                5535021441100707,
                5331217916806887,
                5212754109160056,
                5580039541241472,
                6011450326200252,
                6011141461689343,
                6011886911067144,
                6011835735645726,
                6011063209139742,
                379517444387209,
                377250784667541,
                347171902952673,
                379852678889749,
                345449316207827,
                349968440887576,
                347727987370269,
                370147776002793,
                374465794689268,
                340860752032008,
                349569393937707,
                379610201376008,
                346590844560212,
                376638943222680,
                378753384029375,
                348159548355291,
                345714137642682,
                347556554119626,
                370919740116903,
                375059255910682,
                373129538038460,
                346734548488728,
                370697814213115,
                377968192654740,
                379127496780069,
                375213257576161,
                379055805946370,
                345835454524671,
                377851536227201,
                345763240913232
              ]
```

You are supposed to run `numValid creditcards` and get 94, I'm getting 39.
I suspect my mistake is in `sumDigits` but can't really find it, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: your `doubleSecond` looks strange - seems it will only double anything at the end ... look at your otherwise case (also IMO you should rethink your cases and the way you work with the lists using `splitAt`, `fst` , `snd` , `(!!)` ... screams **pattern match me** ;))

Comment: btw guys: is `sum . map (\_ -> 1)` their way to circumvent the `length` *issue* now? ... are you using Hugs or GHC?

Comment: @Carsten: `length :: [a] -> Int` would have the wrong type. But to be honest, `numValid :: [Integer] -> Int` would be much more appropriate.

Comment: @Zeta true (did not look at it) - it's still strange and it's still interesting if FP101 uses GHC, Hugs or Miranda now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to find those errors. We're going to use [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) to test several properties. Let's start with some properties for `toDigits`:

```
toDigits_prop n = n >= 0 ==> length (toDigit n) === length (show n)
```

It will fail after some tests with something like this:

```
*Main> quickCheck toDigits_prop
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 24 tests):
10
1 /= 2
```

This means that we got only one digit on `10`, where we originally expected two. Let's check the result of `toDigits` on `10`:

```
*Main> toDigits 10
[10]
```

Aha. There's a logic error on `toDigits`, the behaviour on the bounds is wrong, `10` isn't a digit. So change that to `<= 9` instead `<= 10`. While we're at it let's simplify that function, since there is `quotRem` to get both the reminder and `quot` at the same time:

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits n = case n `quotRem` 10 of
  (0, m) -> [m] -- only one digit was left
  (q, m) -> toDigits q ++ [m]
```

Note that this function is somewhat inefficient, we can make it faster if we reverse the digits at the same time:

```
toDigitsRev :: Integer -> Integer
toDigitsRev n = case n `quotRem` 10 of
  (0, m) -> [m]               -- only one digit was left
  (q, m) -> m : toDigitsRev q -- add current digit left
```

Either way, let's check whether the new version of `toDigits` holds:

```
*Main> quickCheck toDigits_prop
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Allright. Let's check whether this passes all tests:

```
*Main> numValid creditcards
94
```

Seems like now everything is fine. So the key is to check properties of your functions. Note that several functions can be written easier, e.g.

```
doubleSecond :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
doubleSecond xs = zipWith ($) (cycle [id, (2*)]) xs
-- or
doubleSecond (x:y:xs) = x : 2 * y : doubleSecond xs
doubleSecond xs       = xs

sumDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumDigits xs = sum (concatMap toDigits xs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I see what I did wrong.